# How to click a specific page after login in scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I would like to write the following flow code with scrapy.

```
1. Login -> 2. Click on a specific page -> 3. crawl a specific URL
```

Since I can not access specific URL unless I click on a specific page, I would like to use scrapy to click on a specific page like No. 2.

Is there such a function on scrapy? Or do I have to use a tool called selenium?

I understand how to code No. 1 and No. 3, but I am at a loss as to how to do No. 2.

Please let me know if you have any hints.

Comment: yes you have to use selenium, you can do all your tasks in selenium without scrapy

Comment: By *click on a specific page* you mean clicking a link leading to that *specific page*? Or does it mean interacting with some other element? If the former one, you don't have to use any kind of browser, you can simply yield a `Request` to that *specific page* with Scrapy.

Comment: If a javascript on the page generates the URL there's no Request-ing around it, you need Selenium :D

Comment: Thank you for your Valuable comments.If you don't mind, have you seen my new question on the link below?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099521/is-there-a-way-to-use-webdriver-of-selenium-with-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @TomášLinhart 
Unfortunately, it is close to the latter one.

Comment: So, I agree that working with Selenium will be appropriate for simulating clicks, but would like to point out that there are ways you can work with Scrapy in such situations too. If it is some form that you are working with, there are FormRequets. Or if the objective of the button click is to load some page, you can directly get the link from scrapy and open the page,etc.

Comment: So would be better if you can tell us which website it is you are working with and which button click is required. Might work out with Scrapy alone.